# Skip Logon Password in Windows 10

Tags: windows

I want to go straight without entering password when logon Windows 10. As I have several PCs which need to do this task. I want to create a batch file to perform the job more efficiently. I have tried the following scripts but they does not work.
I searched over web but still not able to find the solution. My Windows 10 version is 21H2.

```
Echo ByPass Login Password 
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device" /v 
DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
wmic useraccount where name='tester' set PasswordRequired=false
```

---

[image]

This is the screenshot before running the batch script

and after running the script, it does change at all.

Comment: [Provide a screenshot of netplwiz and make sure it clearly indicates if `users must enter a user name and password to use this computer" has been enabled or disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1127222/windows-10-build-10586-545-inside-hyper-v-automatic-login-not-working-with-netpl/1127269#1127269)

Comment: You should attempt to find the registry key linked to that checkbox, set that key, this will allow you to automatically log into whatever profile you set. I can't help you since you didn't edit your question